# Container IP Random

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, redis

I'm docker newbie. 'm running mongoDB in a container and redisDB in an other container and i'm linking this tow databases to my nodeJS project wich is running in a third container. In order to connect to my databases i'm putting the IPs of my containers in my source code but everytime i'm restarting a container the IP is changing so i have to change it in my source code,How can i deal with this problem?

Answer (score 3):

as Michael just said, you can specify an IP Address via the "--ip" parameter

**Example :**

> docker run -d --name="mongoDB" --ip=172.10.0.1 -p=12720:12720 imageIdOrTagName

(Don't forget it is "--ip" and not "-ip)

For further information, please consider reading the "Docker Networking Documentation" page.

If you have any other questions, feel free to ask.

**EDIT For Docker < 1.10:**

[This github issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/19001) references what you are asking :

> Allow user to choose the IP address for the container

It has been integrated in Docker 1.10.0 trough the "docker run --ip=..." command

For older versions, itoffshore presented a temporary solution  [right here](https://it-offshore.co.uk/linux/debian/36-giving-docker-containers-static-ip-addresses).

Hope it will help.

Have a good day,

Nicolas.

Comment: thanks everyone for replying :) still facing a problem with --ip flag provided but not defined: --ip

Comment: What version of docker are you using ? Can you please print the exact command and exact error message ?

Comment: Hey Nicolas  i'm using Docker version 1.8.3 and this is the command: docker run -d --name="mongoDB" --ip=172.10.0.1 -p=12720:12720 containeName  /usr/bin/mongod but i'm getting flag provided but not defined: --ip

Comment: Thanks Nicolas for your help i really appreciate that,thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the IP address of the container in the docker run command line with `--ip="<ip address>"`

Comment: but this can be configured only for a user-defined network, not for the bridge archetype.

Comment: i'm trying this :docker run -d --name="mongoDB" -ip=172.10.0.1 -p=12720:12720  containerName /usr/bin/mongod but still doesnt Work

Comment: Probably because it is `--ip`and not `-ip`: `docker run -d --name=mongoDB --ip=172.10.0.1 -p 12720:12720 containerName /usr/bin/mongod`